# How to get max column using sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with year,month,day as following.

```
Year      Month Day
2015      10    28
2015      10    29
2015      10    29
2015      10    30
2015      10    30
2015      10    30
2015      11    4
2015      11    5
2015      11    9
2015      11    19
2016      1     31
2016      4     1
```

I want to get the highest year and the corresponding highest month in that year and the day of that year, month columns

Output:

`2016   4   1`

If the table doesn't contain 
`2016   1   31
2016    4   1`

rows the output will be
`2015   11  19`

Comment: Do you mean that you want the latest date per year?

Comment: Why don't order by desc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    Y SMALLINT,
    M TINYINT,
    D TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Y DESC, M DESC, D DESC) WITH(IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Y, M, D)
VALUES
    (2015, 10, 28), (2015, 10, 29),
    (2015, 10, 29), (2015, 10, 30),
    (2015, 10, 30), (2015, 10, 30),
    (2015, 11, 4 ), (2015, 11, 5 ),
    (2015, 11, 9 ), (2015, 11, 19),
    (2016, 1 , 31), (2016, 4 , 1 )

SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM @temp
ORDER BY Y DESC, M DESC, D DESC
```

results -

```
Y      M    D
------ ---- ----
2016   4    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use max function in sql.

```
SELECT max(Year) as Year, Month, Day FROM table_name.
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Check this example.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    Y SMALLINT,
    M TINYINT,
    D TINYINT,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Y DESC, M DESC, D DESC) WITH(IGNORE_DUP_KEY=ON)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (Y, M, D)
VALUES
    (2015, 10, 28), (2015, 10, 29),
    (2015, 10, 29), (2015, 10, 30),
    (2015, 10, 30), (2015, 10, 30),
    (2015, 11, 4 ), (2015, 11, 5 ),
    (2015, 11, 9 ), (2015, 11, 19),
    (2016, 1 , 31), (2016, 4 , 1 )

; with cte as
(
    select cast ( cast (y as varchar(15)) +'-' + cast (m as varchar(15)) + '-' + cast (m as varchar(15)) as date) dt , y , m, d
    from @temp
)
select top 1 y,m,d from cte order by dt desc

delete @temp where y = '2016' 

; with cte as
(
    select cast ( cast (y as varchar(15)) +'-' + cast (m as varchar(15)) + '-' + cast (m as varchar(15)) as date) dt , y , m, d
    from @temp
)
select top 1 y,m,d from cte order by dt desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain the values represent valid dates, you can convert them to a date and get the MAX of that:

```
SELECT DATEPART(year, MAX(CAST(Y as varchar(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(M AS varchar(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(D AS varchar(2)), 2))),
    DATEPART(month, MAX(CAST(Y as varchar(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(M AS varchar(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(D AS varchar(2)), 2))),
    DATEPART(dd, MAX(CAST(Y as varchar(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(M AS varchar(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(D AS varchar(2)), 2)))
FROM @temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query (replace your table name)

```
SELECT TOP 1 YEAR, MONTH, DAY  
FROM YOUR_TABLE
ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MONTH DESC, DAY DESC
```